# Trouble installing pydev for Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've installed eclipse and now I'm trying to integrate pydev. In the eclipse SDK, I clicked on "Help", than "Install new software", and then "Add". Then the Add Repository box pops up and under "name" I type in "pydev" and under "location", I type in "http://pydev.org/updates/". It should accept that input but I get an error message that says "duplicate location". Any idea why that's happening. I'm using Python 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you already have PyDev set up as a location.  Go to `Help/Install new software`, but instead of clicking `Add`, click on the drop down box just to the left.  That will show you all of the locations which are already set up.  If the Pydev update URL is already there, just select it and then PyDev should show up as an option to install below.

Comment: @Mike if the answer worked, then please select the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

To check if you really have installed PyDev, go to

1. Help->Install New Software.
2. Click "What is already installed?"

If you can see something like this "Pydev for Eclipse", then PyDev is already installed.